# Upload array of images to server

Tags: flutter

I am having array of image to upload to sever when i upload  a set of images its uploading last image only how can i solve this,

```
  void uploads() async
{
var multipartFile;
var uri = Uri.parse( Config.URL + "Posts/Cube_Post_Submit");
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
for(int i=0;i<image.length;i++)
{
  print(image[i]);
  var stream = new 
 http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(image[i].openRead()));
  var length = await image[i].length();
  multipartFile  = new http.MultipartFile('attachments', stream, length,
      filename: basename(image[i].path));
}   request.files.add(multipartFile);

request.fields['User_Id'] = Config.USER_ID;
request.fields['Cubes_Id'] = jsonstring;
request.fields['Post_Text'] =  "hello";
request.fields['Post_Category'] = "Story";
request.fields['Post_Link'] = "";
var response = await request.send();
print(response.statusCode);
response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value)
{
  print(value);
});
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding the `multipartFile` to `request.files` outside the for loop. Move it inside...

```
void uploads() async {
  var uri = Uri.parse(Config.URL + 'Posts/Cube_Post_Submit');
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
  for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
    request.files.add(
      http.MultipartFile(
        'attachments$i',
        http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(image[i].openRead())),
        await image[i].length(),
        filename: basename(image[i].path),
      ),
    );
  }

  request.fields['User_Id'] = Config.USER_ID;
  request.fields['Cubes_Id'] = jsonstring;
  request.fields['Post_Text'] = 'hello';
  request.fields['Post_Category'] = 'Story';
  request.fields['Post_Link'] = '';
  var response = await request.send();
  print(response.statusCode);
  response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
    print(value);
  });
}
```

Comment: can you confirm flutter MultipartRequest allows multiple attachments under the same name?  I'm only getting the last one sent to my server.  I made sure to include the add part in the loop.

Comment: @user3249281 I'm pretty sure the `field` parameter should be unique for each `MultipartFile` added to the request. For example `'attachments$i'`

Comment: @RichardHeap you are correct. i was trying to emulate the HTML multiselect form option that allows you to do something like `name="inputName[]"` and add multiple files with the same field parameter (ex: inputName).  it actually added the files to the request/multipart object (which i could validate with `request.files.length`).  however, only 1 of them got passed to the server in the POST.  changing the code to make the `field` parameters different worked in them being all sent to the server. i didn't notice in your code you did this with the change from `attachments` -> `attachments$i` thx!

Comment: hi sir, how about using chopper library ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58689156/multipart-in-flutter-using-chopper-library